# Why can't the right hand side of a rule in Makefile be recognized by using $?

Tags: c, makefile

So I created a rule to convert all .c files to .o files. I used variable `$` to place the right hand side of the rule into the recipe. The left hand side is ok with $@, but the right hand side is empty. I remember I did a similar Makefile with `$`, and it worked.

```
CFLAGS =-c -g

all:server client

server:server.o
        gcc -o server server.o

client:client.o
        gcc -o client client.o

clean:
        rm *.o server client

%.o:%.c
        gcc ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $
server.o : server.c
client.o : client.c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be `$<`, not simply `$`. See `info "(make) Automatic Variables"`.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I am learning from a book, and it seems to miss the `<` character.